# New user is posting the same code over and over again from three different accounts

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, sock-puppets

A user keeps posting basically the same code, varying the question, but each time fails to trim down the code into a succinct snippet. The question is basically always "I want to build a web shop, it doesn't work, debug my code for me". The questions are all poor quality, and by their nature and un-focusedness will not help any other user in the future.

The user has created at least three different accounts, of which one at least is already deleted (I can't tell if it was banned or deleted by the user).

Seeking debugging help is allowed, but I think the questions are of poor quality. Meanwhile all of them are already answered and the gist of the solution is usually that the asker was not using a framework or library function correctly. On most of them I voted to close either as "Caused by typo or otherwise not fit to help future users" or "needs clarification" but the questions do not attract other votes. So I wonder how are we supposed to deal with those questions?

Comment: This is best handled by elected moderators, otherwise it's bound to become a witch hunt. Please flag one of the posts for moderator attention and describe the issue in detail, so that they can take the appropriate actions on those posts. Exposing someone to the community like this is unlikely to be fruitful.